# Asking about a paper in a foreign language

Tags: discussion, languages

There's a nice binomial identity I am trying to understand. There are various algebraic proofs, but I am really interested in a combinatorial proof.

Some reading lead me to a monograph by a French mathematician that contains a combinatorial proof. Unfortunately, I don't speak French and I wasn't able to figure it from the text without it.

1. Can I ask a question asking for assistance in explaining the proof by members with some proficiency in French? (The monograph is available freely from the author's website)
2. If the answer to the previous question is negative, can you suggest me who to turn to with this problem?

Comment: I as a low level user see no problem in what you asked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you are welcome to do so.

Comment: (This is an opinion, and not necessarily an official position of the website.  I'm posting it as an answer in part so that up/downvotes can show agreement/disagreement.)

Comment: I agree. "Here is a proof that I cannot follow" questions are better than "Prove X, kthx" -- in particular when the OP specifies the confusing part(s).

Comment: Thank you for the approval, from the upvotes and Georges's answer I assume that this answer is accepted not only be me but also by the community. I will go over the proof in a few days and try to summarize my difficulties.

Answer (score 7):

I'm French, and speak English fluently. I'd be glad to help you.

Answer (score 4):

French a foreign language? 100,000,000 (or rather 100.000.000) people just say *NON !*
    More seriously, of course you can ask for assistance!

Comment: It is foreign to StackExchange network, in the sense that SE does not speak it... this is actually a serious drawback, for a site with global reach to not have language options for user interface, etc.

Comment: I think that this a plus in the sense that most programming documentation is in English as well. If you know English, you have access to most of the content. Making localized questions would require me to check with at least two languages.

Comment: Dear friends, my first line was just a childish joke: don't read anything serious in it. I'm perfectly happy with English being the new international language, taking over the role Latin used to have.

Answer (score 2):

I can also be of help with the French